# Adding new line to here string

Tags: linux, bash

How to add line breaks inside [here strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80362)?
I think it's very useful.
For example:

```
gpg -e <<< 'login: my_login\npassword: my_password'
```

I know about the `-e` option for [`echo`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Bash you can use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html).

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to `string`, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Example:

```
cat <<< $'foo\nbar'
```

The output is:

```
foo
bar
```

It's also possible to use an explicit newline character; you need to quote it:

```
cat <<< "foo
bar"
```

Notes:

- The mechanism of the here string adds exactly one newline character to the end of the string automatically. This is by design and you cannot turn this off.
- I don't know `gpg` and I cannot tell if the string you're trying to pass makes sense.
- To pass multiple lines the syntax of [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) may be a better choice. Example:

  ```
  cat << EOF
  foo
  bar
  EOF
  ```

Comment: Can I use heredoc outside of a script, just in plain text? 
Also why you put `$` before string?

Comment: I already tried heredoc and failed, can you please show an example with line breaks?

Comment: @ДавидШико Example added. I also removed possibly misleading `$` characters from the main example.

Comment: Thank you, I get you, you just hitting enter instead of `\n`. Also I thought that `EOF` is a special symbols :)

Comment: `EOF` as used above can be any SINGLE word. e.g. replace both instances of `EOF` with `ENDHERE` and it will work just as well.